# Processwire admin credentials are not working in production but they do on local

Tags: processwire

I've been working on a website built with processwire, everything went fine. We put the site on production and it was doing ok. Suddenly one day it stopped recognizing the admin credentials (this happened 5+ days after I did the last change to the project). When the website owners told me what was happening, I myself tried to log into the admin account and the login page just refreshes, no error, no nothing. 
I did the project setup 4-5 times just backing up the data base, 777 permissions to assets, cache and sessions folder, erasing the cache and sessions folder content as well and nothing worked.
BUT the weird thing is that I can run the same project locally (using the same database, files, everything, I tested it and yeah, it's the same database) and the credentials are working is if nothing even happened.
Tried to reset the password and with the code snippet that processwire gives us to reset the password it still works locally but not in the production ftp server.

I don't know what should I share of my project in order to make it easy to understand.

Comment: Hi Angel, I recommend you to get in touch directly on the support forum of ProcessWire, there we should be able to help you better as this issue look like more a sysadmin work. (I am an experienced user of ProcessWire.)
Still checking, I think we alread threaded this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, the thing was that I needed to add `session.auto_start = false` in my php.ini file.

I don't really know why this suddenly changed but there it is, hope this helps someone in the future.